# Get only FolderName into datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to just get the subfoldername and not the FULLNAME into a serparate column in my datatable. Please help.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DataTable ReportsDT = new DataTable("ReportsDT");
    ReportsDT.Columns.Add("Name");
    ReportsDT.Columns.Add("FolderName");
    DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Reports"));
    DataRow ReportDTRow = ReportsDT.NewRow();
        foreach (FileInfo fi in DirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
            ReportDTRow = ReportsDT.NewRow();
            ReportDTRow["Name"] = fi.Name;
            ReportDTRow["FolderName"] = fi.FullName;
            ReportsDT.Rows.Add(ReportDTRow);  
        }
}
```

Comment: So what problem are you having? And can't you fix the indentation?

Comment: do you mean the parent folder?

Comment: Path.GetDirectoryName()?

Comment: fi.FullName give me too much info. If a directory is c:\reports\fd3\File.txt. I only need fd3 to be displayed in my "FolderName" row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DirectoryInfo` to get information on a given directory. You have a copy supplied in the `FileInfo` instance under `fi.Directory`:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in DirInfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
    ReportDTRow = ReportsDT.NewRow();  
    ReportDTRow["Name"] = fi.Name;  
    ReportDTRow["FolderName"] = fi.Directory.Name;                   
    ReportsDT.Rows.Add(ReportDTRow);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See sample code below:

```
string[] folders = fi.FullName.Split('\\');
string subFolderName = folders[folders.Length - 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for

```
ReportDTRow["FolderName"] = fi.Directory.Name;
```

You could also just split the string on the path separator and parse it out yourself, but the above should work nicely assuming I understand what you want.